# Sort Array of Objects Based on Numeric Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an array like so:

```
[
   { Orange: 5 },
   { Red: 575 },
   { Green: 6544 },
   { Blue: 1307 }
]
```

The desired outcome is:

```
[
   { Green: 6544 },
   { Blue: 1307 },
   { Red: 575 },
   { Orange: 5 }
]
```

I've been trying to use the sort operator after looking through Stack Overflow: `myArray.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance)`. However, the issue I'm running into is the key is not standardized. All the examples I'm finding have the same key but i'm trying to sort on a numeric value with non standard keys.

When mapping through the above array, I'm able to access the key like so:

```
let ungroupedArr = [
   { Orange: 5 },
   { Red: 575 },
   { Green: 6544 },
   { Blue: 1307 }
]

ungroupedArr.map(element => {
   //this is the key
   Object.keys(element)[0]
})
```

I'm trying to get a more verbose sort solution using the above map style logic (where I have access to each element in the array. However, I've hit a wall and I'm not sure where to go next.

Any idea how I would go about working this out?

Comment: Then use your map example in your sort ([Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) is also a method). But the question is why do you have non-normalized objects?

Comment: I'm pulling product variant data from an api and then sorting the variants based on inventory levels. I'm sure I could restructure the data to normalize the objects but didn't really see a need to. Are there any issues with using non-normalized objects?

Comment: *'...didn't see a need to'* but here you are asking for a convoluted sort solution. The issues are as you've laid out in your question, the need to access keys and values for any manipulation and the reliance on index in accessing those. Plan ahead and structure your data in a meaningful way. `{color: 'Orange', count: 5}` This is easily done at the same time as grouping/counting.

Comment: Yeah I was being dumb. I refactored and everything is so much easier. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const arr = [ { Orange: 5 }, { Red: 575 }, { Green: 6544 }, { Blue: 1307 } ];

const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => Object.values(b)[0] - Object.values(a)[0]);

console.log(sorted);
```